# Is aws SQS able to support avro messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, avro, amazon-sqs

Is aws SQS able to support avro messages?
I need to send avro format messages directly to aws sqs.
Is that possible

Comment: See the [SendMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) docs for valid message content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avro supports [serialization to JSON](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#json_encoding). SQS [supports JSON messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html).

Comment: So i have to use A message can include only XML, JSON, and unformatted text as per the docs?. and convert to from json?

Comment: Since only certain characters are allowed in an SQS message, I think you could run into issues with the binary Avro serialization, so I suggest using Avro's JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The body of an SQS message is completely user-defined and controlled. SQS wraps its meta data around your raw body, so you can use avro message format, or just about any other format,  as long as your consumer process knows what to expect.

Comment: according to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html it doesnt?? Can you please give me an example using avro?

Comment: Sadly this answer is wrong. You can try to send binary avro in a SQS message, but that will result in error 400 `InvalidMessageContents`. The documentation linked is correct, and it will only accept JSON or XML.